# return for SwitchMap in Rxjs - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using for the first time switchMap. It's telling me to return "something", but when I put a return it doesn't work.

```
 @Effect()
  subData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.SEARCH_SUB_DATA),
    map(action => action['payload']),
    switchMap(payload => { //Payload gets highlighted in red
      const repos = this.githubSearch.getRepos(payload);
      const followers = this.githubSearch.getFollowers(payload);
      const starred = this.githubSearch.getStarred(payload);
      return forkJoin([repos, followers, starred]).subscribe(results => {
        this.store.dispatch(
          new UserActions.SuccessSubData({
            user: payload,
            repos: results[0],
            followers: results[1],
            starred: results[2]
          })
        );
        return of(results);
      });
    })
  );
```

> Argument of type '(payload: never) => Subscription' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type '(value: never, index: number) =>
>   ObservableInput<{}>'.   Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type
>   'ObservableInput<{}>'.

**UPDATE BASED ON ANSWER PROVIDED**

```
@Effect()
      subData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ActionTypes.SEARCH_SUB_DATA),
        map(action => action['payload']),
        switchMap(payload => {
          return forkJoin(
            this.githubSearch.getRepos(payload),
            this.githubSearch.getFollowers(payload)
          );
        }).subscribe(results => {
          this.store.dispatch(
            new UserActions.SuccessSubData({
              user: payload,
              repos: results[0],
              followers: results[1]
            })
          );
        })
      );
```

Here's the picture showing the errors

[image from error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbYS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Effect()
  subData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.SEARCH_SUB_DATA),
    map(action => action['payload']),
    switchMap(payload => {
      return forkJoin(
        this.githubSearch.getRepos(payload),
        this.githubSearch.getFollowers(payload)
      ).pipe(map(([repos,followers]) => //return success action here), catchError(error => of(//return failaction))
    })
  )
```

Usually you don't have to subscribe, it will just return the stream and let ngrx handle the subscriptiona and unsubscription. SO here I am mapping success and failure callback actions. They will be automatically triggered by ngrx.

Comment: Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge an `Observable` with a `Subscription` and also when use `forkJoin` you are using with two `undefined` values. Code below must work for your case.

```
@Effect()
  subData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.SEARCH_SUB_DATA),
    map(action => action['payload']),
    switchMap(payload => {
      return forkJoin(
        this.githubSearch.getRepos(payload),
        this.githubSearch.getFollowers(payload)
      );
    })
  ).subscribe(results => {
      this.store.dispatch(
        new UserActions.SuccessSubData({
          user: payload,
          repos: results[0],
          followers: results[1]
        })
      );
    });
```

Comment: Hola parce! thanks for the help. This didn't work. No every word 'payload' things is an object instead of a string and the ``.subscribre()`` is in red because aparently switchmap doesnt return an observable

Comment: Yeah my bad, I edited the answer, I am pretty sure it must work now.

Comment: still same issue. Idk if it makes a difference that I have the switchMap inside of an effect. I have updated my questions with your code and attached an image

Comment: I just edited again, it turns out you have get rid of brackets in forkJoin.

Comment: same error :( I have updated my questions with the code without brakets and udpated image too

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! okay so I copy pasted the your code and the only thing that can't find is the payload in ```user:payload```

Comment: I handled the payload issue. All i did was set it to a global variable and use the global variable. it compiles but in the browser it tells me ```pipe is not a function```